# selenium undetected_chromedriver.v2 403 Error Forbidden

Tags: python, selenium, http-status-code-403

Использую `undetected_chromedriver.v2` для парсинга `https://shop.mts.ru`.
Все работает, все хорошо, но, если добавить аргумент `options.add_argument('--headless')`, то при переходе по ссылке, возникает http 403 ошибка.
Без этого аргумента, на windows браузер открывается и ссылка тоже, но мне нужно запустить код на сервере.
Есть варианты, обойти ее?
Эти аргументы добавлял, не помогают:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
```

Comment: попробуйте UserAgent - "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"  И ещё, я не знаю точно, но надо проверить что НЕ установлена переменная webdriver в true (или как-то так называется) при открытой странице

Comment: @Виктор не помогло..

Comment: @Виктор можешь поподробнее про переменную webdriver? Что то в первый раз слышу.

Comment: все управляемые там Selenium и т.п. можно просечь по наличию установленной переменной (у каждого своя). Т.е. страница (скрипт на ней) смотрит что переменная есть - значит это робот. Я запускал скрипт на странице, до передачи управления странице, скрипт, который удалял её. Может сейчас что-то и поменялось, но всё таки

Comment: Здесь много чего есть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver Искать "Changing the property value of navigator for webdriver to undefined"

Comment: Вызовите из Вашего скрипта https://bot.sannysoft.com/ - там много параметров увидите, это тестер на робота

Comment: @Виктор да, находил похожие топики. Этот скрипт в каких моментах запускать? Сначала скрипт, потом `driver.get(url)`?

Comment: Там же написано  driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
  "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })
  """
})

Comment: @Виктор я имел ввиду, порядок выполнения. 1) выполнить скрипт 2) Перейти на нужную страницу.

Comment: Судя по всему - да. Но сначала без handless на страницу https://bot.sannysoft.com/ зайдите и посмотрите что детектится